# How do I remove the random Unicode symbol at the end of my string output?

Tags: c, unicode, logic, division

So what I'm trying to achieve is long division of a string by a single-digit number, both being arguments. The output is a string comprising of the quotient, followed by the character *'R'*, followed by the remainder.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* str_div_by_digit(const char* num,int digit)
{
    char *ans=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

    int index = 0;
    int n = strlen(num);
    int dividend = num[index] - 48;

    while(dividend < digit && index+1 < n)
    {
        dividend = dividend * 10 + (num[++index] - 48);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(n > index)
    {
        char ans1 = 48 + (dividend / digit);
        ans[i++] = ans1;
        if(index == n-1)
        {
        dividend = dividend % digit;
        index++;
        }
        else
        {
        dividend = (dividend % digit) * 10 + (num[++index] - 48);
        }
    }
    int x = strlen(ans)-1;
    if(x==0)
    {
        ans[i++] = 48;
        dividend = dividend % digit;
    }

    ans[i++] = 'R';
    ans[i] = 48 + dividend;
    
  //void free(void *num);

    void free(void *ans); // Thanks @WhozCraig for pointing this out.

    return ans;
}

int main() 
{    
    printf("%s\n",str_div_by_digit("15",6));
    printf("%s",str_div_by_digit("15002",5));
    printf("%s\n",str_div_by_digit("10000000000000000000000000000003",5));
    printf("%s",str_div_by_digit("1237657129312587312493712539",7));
}
```

This is my output:

```
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Whatever> program.exe
2R3 // Correct
3000R2╬ // Correct except for last character.
2000000000000000000000000000000R3 // Correct
176808161330369616070530362R5☻►☻ // Correct except for last character(s?).
```

As you can see, I get the expected output for the first and third function calls but for the second and fourth, there's always a random Unicode as the last character.

Pls help (and sorry if this question is dumb/not allowed, I'm new :p).

Comment: You're feeding unterminated strings in several places. `malloc` does not zero-fill its allocations. Now, look at your code and ask yourself, as you modify `ans` content, exactly where do you set the string terminator *ever* ? Unrelated, I have no idea what you think `void free(void *num);` is doing, but the reality is it does nothing and shouldn't even be there.

Comment: OT: Let me be the one to comment: "Don't use _magic numbers_ in code. Since 48 is the decimal value for the ASCII character '0', use the ASCII character '0' instead of 48. The compiler doesn't care, but the readers do...

Comment: You've edited the code to read `void free(void *ans); // Thanks @WhozCraig for pointing this out.`  However, the trouble is that you've written a function declaration (both before and after the edit) — you have not written a function call.  Consequently, no memory is freed.

Comment: I get 20R3 for the first case.  Typo?  Missing newlines after case 2 and 4 means output doesn't match either.

Comment: I cannot believe that @WhozCraig recommended to return a freed pointer to code which then actually uses/dereferences that (assuming a fix of the prototype!=call issue). Even if there are deleted comments...

Comment: Use calloc() instead of malloc()

Comment: @Yunnosch you'd be right not to believe it, because I didn't. The change with-comment-added sporting my name is what I call a 'pure guess'. There was no deleted comment. the OP simply didn't understand the first comment in this thing you see above.

Comment: @WhozCraig As I thought. I think in your place I would not be able to resist the temptation to edit and remove the comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot use `strlen()` on a non-terminated char array.  Instead of `x = strlen(ans) - 1` it appears you can just use `x = i - 1`  however I get the wrong value (just like the original) so I think you want to check if `i == 0` also written as `!i`.
2. '\0' terminate `ans` before it's being returned.
3. Use '0' instead of the magic value 48.
4. Eliminated the call to free which doesn't do anything.
5. Rewrote `main()` to eliminate duplication and fix the leaks.
6. (not fixed) Your code only works for single `digit` so maybe assert that?
7. (not fixed) Consider using `for()` loops.  It will make what you iterate stand out more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *str_div_by_digit(const char* num,int digit) {
    char *ans = malloc(100);
    int index = 0;
    int n = strlen(num);
    int dividend = num[index] - '0';

    while(dividend < digit && index+1 < n) {
        dividend = dividend * 10 + (num[++index] - '0');
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(n > index) {
        char ans1 = '0' + (dividend / digit);
        ans[i++] = ans1;
        if(index == n-1) {
            dividend %= digit;
            index++;
        } else {
            dividend = (dividend % digit) * 10 + (num[++index] - '0');
        }
    }
    if(!i) {
        ans[i++] = '0';
        dividend %= digit;
    }
    ans[i++] = 'R';
    ans[i++] = '0' + dividend;
    ans[i] = '\0';

    return ans;
}

int main() {
    struct {
        const char *num;
        int digit;
    } data[] = {
        {"15", 6},
        {"15002", 5},
        {"10000000000000000000000000000003", 5},
        {"1237657129312587312493712539", 7}
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data); i++) {
        char *c = str_div_by_digit(data[i].num, data[i].digit);
        printf("%s\n", c);
        free(c);
    }
}
```